# What is wrong with the below mentioned code for introducing image in html?

Tags: html

I am using the following tag and code to introduce my image in the first HTML page exercise:

```
<img scr="Amar.jpg" alt="Amar's Linkedin profile">
```

But I am only able to see the alternate description and my image is not loading.

I tried to create own HTML page wherein in the introduction page I am trying to insert my own profile photo. But I am getting the above error.

Comment: Where are the code and error?

Comment: <img scr="Amar.jpg" alt="Amar's Linkedin profile">

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. The problem is there is no 'Amar.jpg' file in the same folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure to use proper extension and correct location of image!
And yes, Use "src=..." , seems you wrote it wrong

Comment: It was the mistake pointed out by you @Mayank Devrani. I spelled the attribute wrong.